# Android combining multiple images from database to single bitmap

Tags: android, image, bitmap

i need to combine multiple images to a single bitmap. i need to combine the images in the range from 2-6. The path of the image is taken from my app's database and image is stored in my external sd card. 
i have combined 2 images . But i need to combine 3, 4, 5 and 6 images in to single canvas.

My code for combining 2 images is provided below:-

```
private Bitmap combineImageIntoOne(ArrayList<Bitmap> a) {
        int top = 0;

        int width = 0, height = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < a.size(); j++) {
            width += a.get(j).getWidth();
        }
        height = a.get(0).getHeight();
        Bitmap combineBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(combineBitmap);
        for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {

            System.out.println("image width = " + top);
            comboImage.drawBitmap(a.get(i), top, 0f, null);
            top = top + a.get(i).getWidth();
        }
        System.out.println("combineBitmap combineBitmap..in.."+combineBitmap);
        return combineBitmap;
    }
```

Comment: if you need more information  regarding this question please ask.

Comment: Don't you want to take the max height as well?

Comment: overlap or something else?

Comment: Do you know what that code does?

Comment: `top` should probably be `left`.

Comment: @ dcow i need t take the max height eg: if i have 3 images two images height 200 then my third image height should be 400 and combine in single frame

Comment: @dcow in this code it will combine 2 images side by side

Comment: You know that height and top correspond to the y (or vertical) axis, and width and left correspond to the x (or horizontal) axis?  Operating in that context, what if the Bitmap in position 1 is taller than the Bitmap in position 0?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can combine 3, 4, 5 and 6 images in to single canvas by the same code.
If you want to use the tallest bitmap's height,you can change the code like this.

```
//get the max height 
    height = a.get(0).getHeight();
    for (int j = 0; j < a.size(); j++) {
        width += a.get(j).getWidth();
        if(height<a.get(j).getHeight()){
            height=a.get(j).getHeight();
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can  control by change the final Bitmap's Height.

Comment: iam new to android so can u pls provide an example.

Comment: you can change the value "height" to change the final Bitmap's Height.(Bitmap combineBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);)